# How to access phpmyadmin from other computer in the same network?

Tags: phpmyadmin

What do I configure in wampserver so that I could access phpmyadmin from other computer in the same network.

And how do I access it from the browser?

Answer (score 1):

you would need to use http://computerIP/phpmyadmin to access it. You will need to ensure that port 80 is open on the Firewall before attempting to connect.

Comment: won't it work if I try to access it on the server itself using the method that you said. I get 403 forbidden

Comment: are they windows are linux machines?